# What can be done as the heroku is showing the following log?

Tags: node.js, bash, postgresql, heroku

I am using Polymer.JS on the front end and using nodejs along with postgresql as backend.

As I start heroku by `heroku restart` and then `heroku open`, I get the following error :

```
2017-02-20T12:17:10.122361+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=boiling-depths-34559.herokuapp.com request_id=8015ffa3-7055-439f-85c3-704747af4a25 fwd="171.61.138.131" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2017-02-20T12:17:10.757071+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=boiling-depths-34559.herokuapp.com request_id=2eab9795-57cf-41f4-8138-afcccbc7267e fwd="171.61.138.131" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I got to know to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` command but the console is saying `bash : rake command not found.

my server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var _ = require('underscore');
var db = require('./db.js');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var middleware = require('./middleware.js')(db);
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());



// serving up static files in Public folder
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


//displaying landing page
app.get('/', function(req, res) {


    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));


});


//storing leads generated from landing page
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var body = _.pick(req.body, 'name', 'email', 'address', 'mobileno');
    db.lead.create(body).then(function(lead) {
        res.json(lead.toJSON());
    }, function(e) {
        res.status(400).json(e);
    });
});


//displaying signin page for students
app.get('/signin', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/app/index.html'));
});



//signing in by student
app.post('/signin', function(req, res) {
    var body = _.pick(req.body, 'loginID', 'password');
    var token;
    var callresponse = {};
    // To find the student instance
    db.student.authenticate(body).then(function(student) {
        //generating token for a student to be wrapped in cookie
        token = student.generateToken('authentication');
        callresponse.student = _.pick(student, 'id', 'student_loginID', 'student_email', 'student_school', 'batchId');
        // To find the batch instance
        db.batch.findById(student.batchId).then(function(batch) {
            callresponse.batch = _.pick(batch, 'id', 'batchname', 'teacherId');
            //To find teacher instance
            db.teacher.findById(batch.teacherId).then(function(teacher) {
                callresponse.teacher = _.pick(teacher, 'id', 'teacher_email', 'teacher_name', 'teacher_mobile', 'teacher_address');
                res.header('StudentAuth', token).cookie('token', token, {
                    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 9999999),
                    httpOnly: false
                }).json(callresponse);
            }, function(e) {
                console.error(e);
                return res.status(401).send();
            })
        }, function(e) {
            console.error(e);
            return res.status(401).send();
        })
    }, function(e) {
        console.error(e);
        return res.status(401).send();
    });
});


//Requesting Home Page by student
app.get('/student', middleware.requireStudentAuthentication, function(req, res) {

    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/app/dashboard/student/index.html'));
});


//Requesting List of upcoming tests by student
app.get('/studentget/upcomingtests', middleware.requireStudentAuthentication, function(req, res) {
    db.batch.findById(req.student.batchId).then(function(batch) {
        db.teacher.findById(batch.teacherId).then(function(teacher) {
            db.testdetail.findAll({
                where: {
                    teacherId: teacher.id,
                    test_status: 'Scheduled',
                    test_for_batches: {
                        $contains: [batch.batchname]
                    }
                }
            }).then(function(testdetails) {
                res.json(testdetails);
            }, function(e) {
                console.error(e);
                return res.status(401).send();
            });
        }, function(e) {
            console.error(e);
        });
    }, function(e) {
        console.error(e);
    });
});


// Requesting Test Questions while taking test
app.get('/studenttake/test/:test_ID', middleware.requireStudentAuthentication, function(req, res) {


    db.testdetail.findOne({
        where: {
            test_ID: req.params.test_ID
        }
    }).then(function(testdetail) {
        res.json(testdetail);
    }, function(e) {
        console.error(e);
    });

});



// Posting student feedback
app.post('/studentfeedback/submit', middleware.requireStudentAuthentication, function(req, res) {
    var body = _.pick(req.body, 'student_loginID', 'student_feedback_subject', 'student_feedback_message');
    // Adding feedback created by student
    db.studentfeedback.create(body).then(function(studentfeedback) {
        req.student.addStudentfeedback(studentfeedback).then(function() {
            return studentfeedback.reload();
        }).then(function() {
            // The successful response call. 
            //Add here any JSON object if you want to send to client-side.            
            res.status(200).send();
        });
    }, function(e) {
        console.error(e);
        return res.status(401).send();
    });
});


//Adding Teacher
app.post('/rootuser', function(req, res) {
    var body = _.pick(req.body, 'teacher_loginID', 'teacher_password', 'teacher_email', 'teacher_mobile', 'teacher_name', 'teacher_address');
    db.teacher.create(body).then(function(teacher) {
        res.json(teacher);
    }, function(e) {
        return res.status(401).send();
    });
});



// display sign in for teachers 
app.get('/teachersignin', function(req, res) {
    res.send("This is where teachers will sign in after authenticate git ");
});



//signing in by teacher
app.post('/teachersignin', function(req, res) {
    var body = _.pick(req.body, 'loginID', 'password');
    db.teacher.authenticate(body).then(function(teacher) {
        res.header('Auth', teacher.generateToken('authentication')).json(teacher.toJSON());
    }, function() {
        return res.status(401).send();
    });
});


//GET Homepage for Teacher



//Creating a new batch
app.post('/teacher/Mybatches', middleware.requireTeacherAuthentication, function(req, res) {
    var body = _.pick(req.body, 'batchname');
    db.batch.create(body).then(function(batch) {
        req.teacher.addBatch(batch).then(function() {
            return batch.reload();
        }).then(function(batch) {
            var batchname = encodeURIComponent(body.batchname);
            res.redirect('/teacher/Mybatches/' + batchname).json(batch.toJSON());
        });
    }, function(e) {
        console.error(e);
        return res.status(401).send();
    });
});


//Getting students in a batch by teacher
app.get('/teacher/Mybatches/:batchname', middleware.requireTeacherAuthentication, function(req, res) {
    res.send("Add students to the new Batch formed called :" + req.params.batchname);
});



//Adding a student in a batch
app.post('/teacher/Mybatches/:batchname', middleware.requireTeacherAuthentication, function(req, res) {
    var batchname = req.params.batchname;
    var body = _.pick(req.body, 'student_loginID', 'student_password', 'student_email', 'student_school');
    //assigning the batch to the request
    db.batch.findOne({
        where: {
            batchname: batchname
        }
    }).then(function(batch) {
        //checking the authenticity of the teacher editing the batches
        if (batch.teacherId != req.teacher.id) {
            console.log("You are not allowed to change details of this section");
            return;
        }
        // Adding the found batch to the request object
        req.batch = batch;
        //creating the student in a batch
        db.student.create(body).then(function(student) {
            req.batch.addStudent(student).then(function() {
                return student.reload();
            }).then(function(student) {
                res.json(student.toJSON());
            });
        }, function(e) {
            console.error(e);
            return res.status(401).send();
        });
    }, function(e) {
        console.error(e);
    });
});



// Creating new Test by teacher
app.post('/teacher/createtest', middleware.requireTeacherAuthentication, function(req, res) {
    var body = _.pick(req.body, 'test_ID', 'test_title', 'test_duration_seconds', 'test_description', 'test_window_duration_start', 'test_window_duration_end', 'test_status', 'test_for_batches', 'test_topics', 'test_questions');
    db.testdetail.create(body).then(function(testdetail) {
        req.teacher.addTestdetail(testdetail).then(function() {
            return testdetail.reload();
        }).then(function(testDetail) {
            res.status(200).send();
        });
    }, function(e) {
        console.log("Not able to connect to server.js file");
        console.error(e);
    });
});



//initializing database models and starting server
db.sequelize.sync().then(function() {
    app.listen(PORT, function() {
        console.log('Express server started on ' + PORT);
    });
});
```

and my DB.js

```
    var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var basename = path.basename(module.filename);
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config = require(__dirname + '/config.json')[env];
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
var db = {};
var pg = require('pg');


var conString = process.env.ELEPHANTSQL_URL || "postgres://postgres:5432@localhost/postgres";
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();

sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(function(err) {
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
    });



db.lead = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/API/models/lead.js');
db.student = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/API/models/student.js');
db.teacher = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/API/models/teacher.js');
db.batch = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/API/models/batch.js');
db.studentfeedback = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/API/models/studentfeedback.js');
db.testdetail = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/API/models/testdetail.js');




// defining associations within models
db.student.belongsTo(db.batch);
db.batch.hasMany(db.student);
db.teacher.hasMany(db.batch);
db.batch.belongsTo(db.teacher);
db.studentfeedback.belongsTo(db.student);
db.student.hasMany(db.studentfeedback);
db.testdetail.belongsTo(db.teacher);
db.teacher.hasMany(db.testdetail);
db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;


client.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like rake may be included in your dev dependencies? Standard Heroku buildpacks don't load dev dependencies as production is the assumed environment. If that's the case, you can either add rake to regular dependecies or use the Heroku supported `postinstall` hook to load whatever dependencies you need, do necessary build tasks, and uninstall the dev dependencies.